# Developing using Anjuta and Glade for GTK2

Tags: linux, glade, gtk2, anjuta

I am developing an app for a system that has GTK2 as the latest GTK library installed. I'm using Anjuta and Glade's wysiwyg design interface.

I've used "project > add library" to add the library support for GTK2
and used the project tab on the left to remove support for GTK3.

When I try running my application I get the following error message:

> CRITICAL **: couldn't load builder file: src/gtk_foobar.ui: required gtk+ version 3.0, current version is 2.24

This error starts coming up as soon as I remove GTK3 as one of the libraries.
I need this application to work on systems without GTK3.

Comment: What version of glade are you using? Can you post your includes and how you load the glade File?

Comment: Seems that you are mixing gtk2/3 functions...anjuta is not the problem, but you should use glade version 3.8.5 which is the current gtk2 support. Also, in anjuta remove gtk+-3.0 dependencies libs.

Comment: I was using glade-3.18.3 and  anjuta-3.12.0, I installed glade 3.8.5 but it's not working with the anjuta version I have, seems like I'll have to download and compile and older version of anjuta or completely drop this IDE

Comment: You can use both appart. Create your widgets using glade and code with anjuta. There's no problem, you can use both, that's what I did; yes I dropped anjuta in order to use geany, but you can use anjuta as pure code editor...leaving the IDE apart.